# Temptation of Bamos

Tags: sin, bamot

What was the powerful temptation of Bamos which continued to remain in Klal Yisroel even during the times of the righteous kings?

> [Melachim I (15:14)](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.15.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) - וְהַבָּמוֹת לֹא־סָרוּ רַק לְבַב־אָסָא הָיָה
>   שָׁלֵם עִם־יְהוָה כָּל־יָמָיו
>   - The shrines, indeed, were not abolished; however, Asa was wholehearted with the LORD his God all his life.
>
> [Melachim II (14:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.14.3-4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) - וַיַּעַשׂ הַיָּשָׁר בְּעֵינֵי יְהוָה רַק לֹא כְּדָוִד אָבִיו כְּכֹל אֲשֶׁר־עָשָׂה יוֹאָשׁ אָבִיו עָשָׂה׃ רַק הַבָּמוֹת לֹא־סָרוּ עוֹד הָעָם מְזַבְּחִים וּמְקַטְּרִים בַּבָּמוֹת׃ - He did what was pleasing to the LORD, but not like his ancestor David; he did just as his father Joash had done. However, the shrines were not removed; the people continued to sacrifice and make offerings at the shrines.
>
> [Melachim II (15:35)](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.15.35?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)- רַק הַבָּמוֹת לֹא סָרוּ עוֹד הָעָם
>   מְזַבְּחִים וּמְקַטְּרִים בַּבָּמוֹת הוּא בָּנָה אֶת־שַׁעַר
>   בֵּית־יְהוָה הָעֶלְיוֹן׃ - However, the shrines were not removed; the
>   people continued to sacrifice and make offerings at the shrines. It
>   was he who built the Upper Gate of the House of the LORD.

Answer (score 6):

The Netziv's introduction to Shir HaShirim deals with this a lot. People had an innate desire to connect to G-d, and for hundreds of years were able to do so in their own backyards. Then along came the Temple in Jerusalem and suddenly they were told "you can't do those anymore; you have to take all that religious passion and funnel it in a much more limited, disciplined way; and if you live far from Jerusalem, only a few times a year." (This is why, according to Netziv, Shlomo wrote Shir HaShirim -- the Temple is built, people stay and rejoice for Sukkos, then they go home and ... hrmph ... nearly six months in which they used to be able satisfy their religious passion, and now they had to put it on hold, mostly; so they come back for Pesach, and he writes about channeling the love of Hashem in the proper way.)

Comment: Interesting - I assumed there was an issue of wanting the convenience of serving Hashem in our own backyard rather than the Beis Hamikdash